# Returning address of target in an array

Tags: c++, function, pointers, for-loop

I can't identify my mistake. I need to create a function `int search (int *p, int s, int n)` that will search the array for target, and if found it it will return the adress yet if not found it will return `NULL`;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int search(int *p , int s, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        if(*p == n)
            return &p;
        p++;
    }

    return NULL; 
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int arr[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    cout << "Enter target: "<< endl;
    cin >> n;

    cout << search(arr, 6, n) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do you know that there is a mistake? Do you get unexpected output? Is there a compiler error?

Comment: I think that p is already the address of the integer (remember that \*p is the value of the integer) so you should just return p not &p (which is the address of the *pointer*.)

Comment: You declared your `search()` function toreturn `int` yet you return an `int**` (although probably want to return an `int*`)

Comment: And the compiler must be screaming at you.

Comment: *i cant identify my mistake* -- You could have solved this yourself if you just experimented a little bit by removing the `&`.  Literally, one backspace key on your keyboard.

Comment: why did i need to delete & form &p?

Comment: `&p` is the address of `p`; you want to return its value, since the value of `p` is the address of the element you're looking for.

Comment: so i dont have to dereference it?

Comment: @kogmaw1337 Dereferencing is what you do in the loop condition - `*p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
return &p;
```

This is the issue that you are experiencing: You are returning address of a local pointer that you use for iterating over the input array.

Since you have used `if(*p == n)` in your code I would suppose that you have been aware that `p` is a pointer already. Then, once found the element you should simply return it right away:

```
return p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning `&p` is definitely an error. `p` is a function parameter, and its life does not extend past the end of its function. In common implementation it resides in the stack and vanishes at return time, or more exactly can be overwritten at any time after the function returns.

But you do not need that. If you want an integer index, you need:

```
return i;
```

and if you really want an address, you should have:

```
int* search ( int *p , int s, int n)        // returns an int* not an int
{
    for(int i = 0; i<s;i++)
    {
        if(*p==n)
        return p;
       p++;
    }
    return NULL;  // you should return a defined value if not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void findItemInVec(std::vector<int> &v ,int number) {
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [number](int &item_in_vec) ->void {
        if (item_in_vec == number) {
            std::cout << &item_in_vec << std::endl;
        }
    });
}


int main()
{   
    std::vector<int> v{ 1,2,5,8,7,6,1 };

    findItemInVec(v, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

The argument in the function is a vector of integer values. The function std::for_each checks every item inside the vector with the iterators help and checks if it has the same value with the number argument. For every check that returns true, it types the address of this item.